# Print raw data when using the Curses development kit (Cdk)

Tags: perl, console, widget, ncurses

My perl program needs to jump between ncurses and a raw console as it executes a system call in a loop, like this (simplified for problem emphasis):

1. init [Cdk](http://search.cpan.org/~glover/Curses-Devkit-4.9.3/)
2. present menu
3. deinit Cdk
4. run system call

Unfortunately Cdk appears to initialize ncurses *at* the `use Cdk` import and not instantiation 
(`Cdk::init()`) and so I don't know how to disable it. This behavior seems completely absurd to me; apart from the loop described above, my program also has a special mode where a database is initialized - this part does not present any kind of menu (only raw console output) yet it would seem that I now have to format all my output with menus - whilst not even using a menu! And again, just to print the program help output now seems to require me to generate a Cdk widget - insane.

**Is there a way to easily jump in and out of ncurses when using Cdk** or am I screwed?

Some example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Cdk;

eval {popupLabel(["popup before init"]);}; # will fail as init() isn't called
print "Test after use\n";                  # won't be printed (which is a problem!)
Cdk::init();
print "Test after init\n";                 # won't be printed
popupLabel(["popup after init"]);
Cdk::end();
print "Test after end\n";                  # won't be printed
```

Comment: As a sidenote, as I'm getting quite desperate, if anyone could provide *ANY* functional console-based widget library for generating a scrollable, multi-item menu list (I've tried Cdk, Curses::Widget::Menu, Curses::UI::ListBox and UDMP - they're all absolutely horrible) then please don't hesitate to give me some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got what I wanted, **scrapping Cdk** for Curses::UI. Thanks mfontani for posting an answer!

Here's my example solution which uses `Curses::UI` and `Curses::UI::Listbox`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Curses::UI;
use Curses::UI::Listbox;

my $cui = Curses::UI->new(-color_support => 1,
              -clear_on_exit => 0);

my $win = $cui->add('window_id', 'Window');

sub user_select {
    my ($cui, $obj) = @_;

    my $item = $obj->get_active_value();

    $cui->leave_curses();

    print "You selected $item!\n";
    sleep(1);
}

my $listbox = $win->add(
            'mylistbox', 'Listbox',
            -onchange    => sub{ user_select($cui, @_) },
            -border      => 1,
            -values      => [1, 2, 3],
            -labels      => { 1 => 'One', 
                      2 => 'Two', 
                      3 => 'Three' },
    );
$listbox->focus();
$cui->mainloop;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following (which uses the newer [Curses](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Curses/) module) seems to do what you want: bits of Curses, and bits of non-Curses intermingled:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Curses;

# Non-Curses
print "Press a key...\n";
<STDIN>;

# Curses
initscr();
addstr(14, 0, "hit a key: ");
refresh();
my $ch = getch();
endwin();

# Non-Curses
print "Hi again, press a key...\n";
<STDIN>;

# Curses again
initscr();
addstr(14, 0, "hit another key: ");
refresh();
my $ch2 = getch();
endwin();

# Non-Curses
print "bye!\n";
```

At least this module was released this January and not (like Cdk, released 1998) last century...

Comment: Sure I can use Curses on its own; however this does not give me the menu widget I'd like. I'm trying fiercely to get Curses::UI::Listbox (Curses::UI has a simple way of exiting curses with the leave_curses method) to function with callbacks, but it keeps terminating as soon as the callback accesses a list element. perldebug isn't providing much insight in cbreak-mode either..

Comment: I would suggest you open another question related to that, and show the exact code that is giving you that problem!

Comment: I would, except that I solved it and posted it here as an answer to my original question. I don't know if that's the right behavior here on SO :/ perhaps I should change the title of my question so as to clarify what was done.